# single column in sql

Tags: sql, mysqli

Can some one tell me how can I display only a single column value in a database using an sql command.

Suppose I have a table say emplyee having fields NAME,ROLL NO.

I want to get output of only the values from the column ROLL NO.I dont want to match it against any criteria.

Answer (score 1):

this is so simple, do this

```
select rollno from employee
```

this will fetch you all the rollno in the table

edit:

```
select rollno from employee limit(5,1)
```

or

```
select top 5 rollno from employee
```

this will give you top five rows only

Comment: If I want to slect only 5 records?

Comment: `select top 5 rollno from employee`

Answer (score 0):

Just a single request like that :

```
select ROLLNO from emplyee
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use

```
    SELECT <column name> FROM <table name>;
```

Answer (score 0):

use this if table name is emplyee

```
  select rollno from emplyee
```

or

```
  select rollno from emplyee where rollno is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT ColumnName FROM Table

[more info on mysql syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

Answer (score -1):

Place the comma separated column names that you want as output right after `select` keyword.
Since you just want to retrieve `rollno` column, use this:

```
select rollno from employee;
```

For more than one column, use comma separated column names as mentioned above. For example:

```
select name, rollno from employee;
```